# Using LiveData property value inside ViewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I'm struggling to find a better and elegant way to solve this specific case which happens a lot on my project.

On my ViewModel, suppose I have this live data property:

```
val limitDate = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

And that variable is set by intent or by a repository fetch, doesn't matter, I'll represent is like a repository fetch:

```
fun fetchDate() {
        useCase.fetchLimitDate.collect { limitDate ->
             limitDate.postValue(limitDate)
        }
}
```

Then right after I set this date to be observed on the view, I need to use this value to calculate something else in another function. If I try to use the same liveData property value, this code ends up not being called since it runs too fast

```
  private fun calculateSomethingWithDate() {
    limitDate.value?.let{ date ->
         //Any logic here 
          repository.saveLimitDate(date)
      }
}
```

If I add an `delay(100)` it works, but definitely won't do that, so I ended up having another property that holds the value of the liveData, and set it on the first function like this:

```
val limitDate = MutableLiveData<String>()
var limitDateValue : String



fun fetchDate() {
   useCase.fetchLimitDate.collect { limitDate ->
     limitDate.postValue(limitDate) //To be observed on view 
     limitDateValue = limitDate
     }
}

private fun calculateSomethingWithDate() {
    repository.saveLimitDate(limitDateValue)
      
}
```

So, any suggestions on how to make it better?

Comment: Your function name called "calculateXXX" but inside of it you called another function "saveXXX", I'm confused. What actually you're trying to do?

Comment: @SamChen function "calculateXXX" is just another viewModel function and saveXXX is a repository function, is just an example. What I'm trying to do is: use the live data value in any way that I want without observing it on the Activity. But if I use: liveDataProperty.value?.let{}  I can't get that value fast enough to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Transformations.map()` to create a customized output (read-only) that updates along with the target `MutableLiveData`, see documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#map(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)).

```
val limitDate = MutableLiveData<String>()

val anotherLiveDataProperty = Transformations.map(limitDate) { date ->
    //Any logic here
}
```

- `Transformations.map()` returns a `LiveData`, you can observe it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sam, but that's not what I'm asking. I edited my question to make it clearer and removed anotherLiveDataProperty.